# Null String for Scanner

Tags: java

I have a problem over my application. I want the app to detect that if the user does not input any value for the string (in other words, just press enter after being asked to input something), the app then asks whether he/she wishes to quit the program or not.
Am I doing it right?

```
words = s.nextLine();   
if (words.equals(null)) {
```

Comment: maybe you should check for empty string, not NULL?

Comment: Try it yourself, and see if it works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you're not doing it right.

`nextLine()` will return an *empty* string if the user just hits return. As far as I can tell it will *never* return `null`. If the end of the input has been reached, it will throw `NoSuchElementException` (unlike `BufferedReader.readLine()` which *will* return null in that case). So you want:

```
if (words.equals(""))
```

or

```
if (words.length() == 0)
```

or

```
if (words.isEmpty())
```

... and use `hasNextLine()` if you want to detect the end of input first.

Answer (score 5):

No, you're not.

If the user simply presses enter, you'll get an empty string, not `null`. This can be checked as

```
if(words.equals(""))
```

If there are whitespaces, this would fail. In that case

```
if(words.trim().equals(""))
```

should work.

Comment: Well, I think I deserve a badge for this... for having the answer accepted where there is an answer from @JonSkeet on the same post! :D

Comment: ... well, even if it was for a few minutes! :P

Answer (score 4):

null is not correct, because what you get is an empty String:

use: 
`words.isEmpty()`
or 
`words.equals("")`
or 
`words.length()==0`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if (words == null || words.length() == 0) {
```

Comment: String has a length() method not length attribute :P

Comment: if 'words' is a null, 'words.equals(null)' will cause null pointer exception

Comment: touché, you're right! i wasn't sure if it was a String or a char[]

Answer (score 0):

the returned string isnt null, its just an empty string.

```
words.equals("");
```

should be correct